# Send emails from localhost?

Tags: php, email

im kinda stuck, i have read some threads where they use google smtp to send mails from localhost.
Im using xampp right now and im trying to use google smtp but it doesn't work what have i done wrong ?

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\page.php on line 48
```

My Code in php.ini:

```
sendmail_from = T***@gmail.com
Gmail SMTP server address: smtp.gmail.com
Gmail SMTP user name: T***@gmail.com
Gmail SMTP password: ****
Gmail SMTP port: 465
Gmail SMTP TLS/SSL required: yes
```

Comment: are you sure you edited the php.ini php is looking at? try phpinfo() to see where your php is looking for mail config.

Comment: What should i search for in php info? He changed so the mail adress im send from is T***@gmail.com - But smtp is still localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the SMTP-Server, Port and authentication credentials in your php.ini.

But for this it's much easier to use the wonderful [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) class.

It's very easy to implement and to use.

You can easily send complex emails (HTML, Attachments) and it has a good support for external SMTP server, including e.g. encryption.

Just take a look at the examples in the "examples" folder or scroll down at the linked page where is an example using SMTP auth in the first code-block.

Comment: That worked awesome, but the reason i didnt use this is because im kinda lazy and i dont have a clue how to write my own, so it justs send "hello world" or something

Comment: When you're lazy PHPMailer is the best choice for you, because all the things (connection etc) is handled by PHPMailer. You only have to set the Host, Port, Credentials and then easy send the mail ;)

Comment: I did that, but one question now i need a "unique" id to get sent with the email, how should i do this? The id gets posted to the database too

Comment: uniqid() will create a unique id based on the microseconds. You can then save this into the database and add this to the emailtext, too.